# Characters are sometimes rendered as symbols on Chrome v42 in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, render, webfonts

Sometimes the characters in our webfont are rendered as symbols instead of normal text. It only seems to affect Chrome v42 and v43 on Windows systems.

This is how it looks like when the problem occurs: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g0AB.png).

The site in question: http://www.ne.se (the screenshot is from the footer)

It does not happen on all pages on the site, and deactivating javascript seems to "fix" the problem. One strange thing is that it only seems to be affecting single words, it never happens when there are two or more words together. It seems to be quite random, sometimes it takes a few reloads (without cache) to trigger the problem.

All tips and pointers are welcome as I have yet to find a similar issue elsewhere.

Comment: Did you ask Google (chrome://chrome/, `report issue` button)? FYI: the issue keeps tenaciously on my Windows 8, Chrome Version 42 (64-bit), all up to date... I guess it has something to do with obscure `@font-face{ font-family: "Gotham Narrow SSm A"; src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;base64...` in linked `masala-ux.min.css`

Comment: I did not, thanks for the tip!